# Pagination buttons aren't in sync with current page

Tags: joomla-3.x, pagination

I have implemented a pagination technique and the pages seems to work well when I edit in the url, but page 1 cannot be clicked and is still active even though I have changed to the second or third page.

http://carplate2.satumalaysiahosting.com/component/sppagebuilder/?view=page&id=62&start=8

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `#__bidding_items` WHERE `state` = '1'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$total = $db->loadResult();

$limit=8;
$limitstart=0;

jimport('joomla.html.pagination');

$pagination = new JPagination($total, $limitstart, $limit);

echo $pagination->getPagesLinks();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$limitstart` argument to the current start item. You can get the value from input:

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();
$limitstart = $app->input->getInt('limitstart', 0);

$pagination = new JPagination($total, $limitstart, $limit, $app);
```